# I can't recast my variable from string to byte or from byte to string

Tags: stata

I have two datasets I would like to `merge` using Stata 15.1. Before I can do this I need to ensure the storage types are the same for the reference variables that I am using to join the data sets, a `Country` and a `year` variable. I changed the `year` variable into byte type with no issues; however, the `Country` variable, which is currently in a `str26` type, comes up with the error `Country: byte invalid`.

I also tried going to my main data file where the `Country` storage type is byte and changing this into a string, but the same error shows, `Country: str26 invalid`.

I have tried using force `recast str26 Country, force`, and beyond this am not sure what to do.

Comment: Byte is a data type that is used to store numbers, not strings (see https://www.stata.com/manuals13/ddatatypes.pdf). I suggest ensuring that your `country` variable is stored as strings with the same number of characters in both datasets that is sufficient to capture the country with the longest name (e.g. str30 should be sufficient) and merge based on `country`. You could also considering recoding the country variable using integers with value labels using `encode`, but you'd  need to ensure that you have the same integer value for each country in both datasets.

Comment: Consider using `dataex` (`ssc install dataex`) to share an example of both datasets.

Comment: In addition, a byte variable is able to store values from -127 to 100. I would worry if my year variable was of the type byte.

Comment: `recast` can't be used to cross the divide between string and numeric variables. Using the value labels (assuming that they exist) to produce a string variable is the safest approach, but consistency of spelling is vital. `merge` is entirely literal and differences in spaces or other punctuation, use of upper and lower case, and longer and shorter versions of the same name could be problematic. The same is true in any other language or environment for whatever function or command is used to combine files.  There is often a detailed editing job ahead and force can't help you.